# Arranging buttons in a circle (Android) with lines connecting them

Tags: android, animation, button, layout, custom-view

I am attempting to create a `Fragment` for an Android application where I have either `Button`s or `ImageButton`s programatically arranged in a circle, with lines drawn from them to the center of the `View`. However, I have become stumped as to how to do this.

From my understanding, I can create a custom `View` in which I can override the `onDraw()` to draw the lines, but I cannot put the `Button`s in this way. I can overlay the custom `View` with a `FrameLayout` or the like, but I do not know what type of layout to use so that the buttons can be arranged in a circle (and that this will work for various screen sizes).

Furthermore, I have to ensure that both the drawn lines and the buttons will be able to be animated together (that is, for instance, the buttons and connecting lines can move off-screen at the same rate as if they were one entity).

I have seen this post, and it is actually very similar to what I would like to do! : [Dynamically arrange Buttons around a Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368863/dynamically-arrange-buttons-around-a-circle) . However, I do not quite have a satisfactory understanding of the answer, particularly how a `Button` can be created in an `onDraw()` with `onClick` still functioning.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated!

Comment: can you put rough design how do you want to put buttons around circle?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368863/dynamically-arrange-buttons-around-a-circle for a starters?

Comment: @JohnnyBroberg, he has already mentioned this link in his question.. :/

Comment: @ChintanRathod In the link I have shown, the provided imgur link gives an idea of what I would like to do. I'll put it here again: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NYQeR.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [CircleLayout](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout) created by dmitry-zaitsev may help you to create what you want.

It has very simple implementation like below.

```
<ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white"
  app:angleOffset="90.0">

  <!-- Add here any views you want -->

</ru.biovamp.widget.CircleLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Second option is [Creating a Rotating Dialer](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/)

Third option is [Android-3D-Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel).

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, I had actually just recently found dmitry-zaitsev's CircleLayout, but your answer is much more thorough than what I found. Thank you!!!